# Asymptotic analysis: Python Big-O homework

Tags: python, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have a homework question that asks me to give a tight big-o estimate of the worst-case time-complexity of the following Python code:

```
sum = 0
i = n
while i > 1:
    for k in range(n*n):
        sum = sum + k*i
    i = i // 2
```

The outer loop would seem to have a O(log n) time-complexity because of the line i = i // 2.
The inner loop appears to have a O(n^2) time-complexity because the range is n*n.
The two loops seem to be independent of each other so would the overall time-complexity be O(n^2)?

Comment: If you had to walk up 100 stairs in 5 different buildings, how many steps would you have to climb?

Comment: The two loops are **not** independent; the other loop loops LogN times, so the inner loop is executed that many times.

Comment: The term "worst-case time-complexity" does not really apply here. You can find the big theta for this algorithm.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I suppose my wording was poor. I meant that the inner loop will still execute n*n times every time the outer loop executes. So you are saying that they correct answer is O(LogN)? So does that mean that the complexity of the inner loop doesn't matter, but instead it only matters how many times it is executed by the outer loop?

Comment: According to your analysis, shouldn't it be `O(n^2lgn)`?

Comment: @Arioth: No, because that would make the loops not dependant..

Comment: Ask yourself: Does the outer loop increase the number of times the inner loop is executed?  If yes, then it's O(log2(n) * n * n)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies. It is clear to me I still don't have a grasp on this concept, but your input has helped me with this particular question.

Comment: In this rather simple case you don't have to rely on guesstimates and approximations. I'd recommend for learning purposes to compute the actual exact number of operations as a function of n (not in O(...)). You can do this in closed form. The resulting formula should then give you a hint at what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You may think of the complexity as number of simple operations needed to complete a given task. Now your outer loop says that you perform a given operation `log(n)` times which you correctly point out in the question. However these operations are not simple - they consist of performing a cycle. This cycle performs `O(n^2)` simple operations as, again, you point out correctly. Now try to think what will be the total number of simple operations performed by the code fragment?

NOTE: in my answer I assume addition and integral division are simple operations.